# Cloth animation weird shelf

Tags: mesh, cloth-simulation

The top has been pinned and cannot move. From where does this shelf at the top of the skirt come from? I guess there is some form of repulsive force. How can I reduce it? Repel is set to 0. The shell remains throughout the entire animation.

EDIT: the effect remains even if I increase the mass to 10. The skirt does not fall over, so down is down.

[image: Initial condition]

[image: First rendered frame]

Comment: Just a wild guess. If the body underneath is set to collision, the outer face thickness (margin) might be too high so the cloth vertices are pushed away. You would need to play with the collision settings of the underlying object or smooth the pinning weights. Cloth settings depend on the scale of the objects, so its hard to say without blend file.

Comment: 1 blender unit = 1 m. The doll is 1.36 m exported from MakeHuman

Comment: Tried to play with the face thickness of the underlying body?

Answer (score 1):

I changed the cloth collision parameters on the collision object that the cloth collides with from `0.008` and `0.003` to `0.002` and `0.001`.

[image]

This solved the problem.

Comment: What parameters did you change? Your answer is getting flagged because it's a little short. If you could add some more detail that would be great :)

Comment: @CharlesL See the suggestion by user2859